# Call lambda expression without asigned it to a delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

in javascript we can create an arrow function like this :

```
let square= (a) => a * a;
```

and call let directly like this :

```
square(1, 2);
```

is there a solution to do something similar to this using c# ?
i tried this but it gives me this error ( the delegate type could not be inferred)

```
var square = (x) => x * x;
```

Comment: No, lambda expressions by themselves do not have a type.

Comment: You have to put `Func<int, int>` or `Func<double, double>` or even `Func<decimal, decimal>`, `Func<int, double>` as labda's type: `var` is not enough: all these possible types can't be *inferred* from `(x) => x * x;`

Comment: In addition to the "not enough type information" issues others are alluding to, there's also the "is this an `Expression` or a delegate?" problem that has to be solved in converting the lambda into something you can store in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the delegate (a method being a function here, like in JavaScript) using a [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.func-2) type to use the [lambda syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions):

```
Func<int, int> square = value => value * value;
```

As @DmitryBychenko pointed out in his answer, we need to specify a type instead of using `var` because C# is a strongly typed OOP compiled language, and not loosely-typed interpreted like JavaScript.

Therefore we can call it:

```
int result = square(2);
```

But with the latest versions of C#, the compiler issues a warning to use a [local method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) instead:

```
int square(int value) => value * value;
```

Lambda syntax is not a type but a language syntax: we cannot "*call a lambda*" because we cannot call a certain line of code in a method directly unless we call the method itself.

Delegates and Func/Action as well as instance and local methods are types: thus we *call a method*.

For example the local method as well as the Func delegate lambda style is exactly the same as:

```
int square(int value)
{
  return value * value;
}
```

There is a little difference between a local delegate or func/action style ([anonymous methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-functions)) and a local method.

[Difference between sending an anonymous function vs. Func/Action to another function with a Delegate parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773833/difference-between-sending-an-anonymous-function-vs-func-action-to-another-func)

[Local function vs Lambda C# 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943117/local-function-vs-lambda-c-sharp-7-0)

[Dissecting the local functions in C# 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-local-functions-in-c-7/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem of

```
 var square = (x) => x * x;
```

is that compiler can't *infer* the *type* of `square` from the right value. It can be

```
 Func<int, int> square = (x) => x * x;
 Func<int, double> square = (x) => x * x;
 Func<double, double> square = (x) => x * x;
 ...
 // if some MyType implements * operator
 Func<MyType, MyType> square = (x) => x * x;
```

That's why you have to provide the desired type *manually*, e.g.

```
 // We square integer (not double, not decimal) values:
 // we take int and return int 
 Func<int, int> square = (x) => x * x;
```

Comment: Or `Expression<Func<int,int>>`, etc.